# How can I get a RSS/ATOM feed for new package releases on launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

How can I get a RSS/ATOM feed update if a project releases a new package?

Take the example of [Back In Time](https://launchpad.net/backintime).

I would like to get an update for their release of

```
“backintime” source package in Sid 
Version 1.0.34-0.1 uploaded on 2014-01-07
```

Answer (score 0):

Here're its rss feeds:

- [Back In Time Announcements](http://feeds.launchpad.net/backintime/announcements.atom)
- [Bugs in Back In Time](http://feeds.launchpad.net/backintime/latest-bugs.atom)
- [Branches for Back In Time](http://feeds.launchpad.net/backintime/branches.atom)
- [Latest Revisions for Back In Time](http://feeds.launchpad.net/backintime/revisions.atom)

I guess the last one is what You need.

Comment: Thanks but none of them actually shows me new package release. I am not interested in single revision changes but major package updates.

Comment: @DamianFill I guess that means there's no feed for stable releases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement but for my case I have no RSS feed.

So I came out with some bash to check current versions,

```
PPA_REPO="https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa"
curl -s $PPA_REPO \
        |awk '/packages_list/,/lower-batch-nav/' \
        |sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' \
        |sed -e "s|)|) \n ---------------|g" \
        |sed -e "s|Uploaded by|Uploaded by \n ===============|g" \
        |sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'
```

Just change the PPA_REPO url acordingly to your needs.